# Omni channel - Chat Agent is online but the chat button on the community still shown offline

Tags: omnichannel

We recently implemented omni channel setup in sandbox org however the visualforce button always remain inactive even when the agent set themselves as online.

We replicated the same setup in personal dev org and it works fine there.

One difference we noticed post capturing the network logs was JSON response missing "isAvailable" attribute in sandbox org.

Can someone help to understand what we might be missing ? We followed all the checks provided by salesforce help document here - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383003&language=en_US&type=1

Dev Org (WORKING)

Request:

```
https://d.la2-c1-ukb.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Visitor/Availability.jsonp?sid=undefined&r=691&Availability.prefix=Visitor&Availability.ids=[5735g000000YcTU]&callback=embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.connection.handlePing&deployment_id=5725g000000YYit&org_id=00D5g00000KD8pI&version=48
```

Response :

```
/**/
embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.connection.handlePing({
    "messages": [{
        "type": "Availability",
        "message": {
            "results": [{
                "id": "5735g000000YcTU",
                "isAvailable": true
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Staging (NOT WORKING)

Request :

```
https://d.la1-c1cs-ph2.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Visitor/Availability.jsonp?sid=undefined&r=694&Availability.prefix=Visitor&Availability.ids=[573170000000KuJ]&callback=embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.connection.handlePing&deployment_id=572170000000IXY&org_id=00D17000000tWaP&version=48
```

Response :

```
/**/
embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.connection.handlePing({
    "messages": [{
        "type": "Availability",
        "message": {
            "results": [{
                "id": "573170000000KuJ"
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Are you using Skills? Does the online agent have the right skill?

Comment: We are not using skill based routing.

Comment: Double check the ids in your setup code - deploymentId, buttonId, orgId.  If you are using a queue in your Chat Button, make sure it is configured with users.

Comment: @JasonClark good point but all checked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was enabling enhanced routing option in omni channel setting. Once we disabled it, chats started working fine.